# Does class and specialization affect starting locations?

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

It seems to be understood that choosing a race impacts the probability of starting locations/climate, but does the same thing happen with your class and specialization? My friend plays an Air Master Sorcerer, and out of six attempts he always ended up in Arctic terrain. It could be a coincidence of course, but just wondering if anyone knows for sure, or based on a large number of games.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, it's not a definitive answer but I ran a short experiment of 20 game starts with two human characters, fire master dreadnought and air master rogue. Result: no apparent bias due to class/specialization.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, the climate has nothing to do with what race you pick, Its completely random.

Comment: Race affects it, as you won't start in randomly generated hostile terrain closer than X hexes to your starting city core. That makes the answer wrong. However, the question was about class and specialization, which DON'T affect starting terrain. For which "No" is the answer.